# Modifying Xcode syntax highlighting to gray-out NSAssert lines

Tags: xcode, syntax-highlighting

I want to modify Xcode syntax highlighting.  Namely, I do a lot of 'NSAsserts', which I find visually distracting, and so I would like lines starting with 'NSAssert' to be a light gray.  This way, I can focus upon my code logic instead of having to cognitively filter-out the NSAssert lines.

Comment: To clarify the scope of my question, I know that I can go into XCode's preferences and change, in 'Fonts & Colors' all 'Other Preprocessor Macros' to gray, but that only changes the word "NSAssert" to gray, and not the whole line.  Also, that is not as fined-grained of a solution as I am hoping for.

Comment: This is the best that Xcode permits you to currently do.

Comment: @blueberry - sounds like an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a lot of these too, and I liked your idea enough to work out the answer. Well, sort of: I have not worked out how to treat NSAsserts as a new item but I have worked out how to make them appear as comments in the syntax highlighter.

1. Create the directory ~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Specifications
2. Copy BaseSupport.xclangspec from /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XcodeEdit.framework/Versions/A/Resources to that directory
3. Apply this patch to the new copy:

```
--- /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XcodeEdit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/BaseSupport.xclangspec    2010-10-05 00:27:45.000000000 +0100
+++ /Users/philwill/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Specifications/BaseSupport.xclangspec    2010-12-14 11:36:51.000000000 +0000
@@ -100,9 +100,8 @@
         Identifier = "xcode.lang.comment.singleline";
         BasedOn = "xcode.lang.comment"; // for text macros
         Syntax = {
-            Start = "//";
-            EscapeChar = "\\";
-            Until = "\n";
+            StartChars = "/N";
+       Match=("//.*$","NSC?Assert[12345]?[[:space:]]*\\([^;]*\\)[[:space:]]*;");
             IncludeRules = ( "xcode.lang.url", "xcode.lang.url.mail", "xcode.lang.comment.mark" );
             Type = "xcode.syntax.comment";
         };
```

Caveats:

1. This will mess up any //-comments
   which contain escaped newline
   characters. Don't do that.
2. This will theoretically slow down
   syntax highlighting a little. I
   haven't noticed any difference.
3. This will affect all languages you use in Xcode which normally allow //-comments.

Comment: So, it isn't an exact answer, but you are at least pointing me in the right direction, which seems to be, "XCode doesn't support this, but you can try hacking "BaseSupport.xclangspec".  Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best that Xcode currently permits you to do.